# How to get new column in dataframe that is based on multiple conditions between two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I am looking to get a column in DF1 that will have values of the "current date" column plus number of days relating the the relevant status and technology in DF2. For example in the below the first value in the "new date" column is 18/03/2022 + 1095 days as it is checking to see if technology = wind and status = construction.

DF 1

| Current Date | Technology | Status | New Date *DESIRED FROM CODE* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18/03/2022 | Wind | Construction | 16/12/2022 |
| 15/02/2022 | Solar | Construction | 15/11/2022 |
| 24/01/2022 | Battery | Application approved | 24/10/2022 |
| 23/09/2020 | Wind | Application approved | 24/03/2023 |
| 18/11/2021 | Solar | Application submitted | 18/11/2023 |
| 25/06/2020 | Solar | Application approved | 25/03/2021 |
| 27/02/2020 | Wind | Application submitted | 25/02/2025 |
| 10/03/2022 | Battery | Application submitted | 09/03/2024 |

DF 2

| Technology | Application submitted | Application approved | Construction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Battery | 730 | 273.75 | 273.75 |
| Solar Photovoltaics | 730 | 273.75 | 273.75 |
| Wind | 1825 | 912.5 | 1095 |
|  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) (if need better accuracy remove `.astype(int)`):

```
df2 = (df2.melt('Technology', var_name='Status', value_name='New Date')
          .assign(**{'New Date': 
                    lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x['New Date'].astype(int), unit='d')}))
print (df2)
            Technology                 Status  New Date
0              Battery  Application submitted  730 days
1  Solar Photovoltaics  Application submitted  730 days
2                 Wind  Application submitted 1825 days
3              Battery   Application approved  273 days
4  Solar Photovoltaics   Application approved  273 days
5                 Wind   Application approved  912 days
6              Battery           Construction  273 days
7  Solar Photovoltaics           Construction  273 days
8                 Wind           Construction 1095 days
```

And then use left join and add column `Current Date`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['Technology','Status'], how='left')
df['New Date'] += pd.to_datetime(df['Current Date'], dayfirst=True)
print (df)
  Current Date Technology                 Status   New Date
0   18/03/2022       Wind           Construction 2025-03-17
1   15/02/2022      Solar           Construction        NaT
2   24/01/2022    Battery   Application approved 2022-10-24
3   23/09/2020       Wind   Application approved 2023-03-24
4   18/11/2021      Solar  Application submitted        NaT
5   25/06/2020      Solar   Application approved        NaT
6   27/02/2020       Wind  Application submitted 2025-02-25
7   10/03/2022    Battery  Application submitted 2024-03-09
```

For match `Solar Photovoltaics` values is possible use split and select first values:

```
df2['Technology'] = df2['Technology'].str.split().str[0]

df2 = (df2.melt('Technology', var_name='Status', value_name='New Date')
          .assign(**{'New Date':  
                  lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x['New Date'].astype(int), unit='d')}))
print (df2)
  Technology                 Status  New Date
0    Battery  Application submitted  730 days
1      Solar  Application submitted  730 days
2       Wind  Application submitted 1825 days
3    Battery   Application approved  273 days
4      Solar   Application approved  273 days
5       Wind   Application approved  912 days
6    Battery           Construction  273 days
7      Solar           Construction  273 days
8       Wind           Construction 1095 days


df = df1.merge(df2, on=['Technology','Status'], how='left')
df['New Date'] += pd.to_datetime(df['Current Date'], dayfirst=True)
print (df)
  Current Date Technology                 Status   New Date
0   18/03/2022       Wind           Construction 2025-03-17
1   15/02/2022      Solar           Construction 2022-11-15
2   24/01/2022    Battery   Application approved 2022-10-24
3   23/09/2020       Wind   Application approved 2023-03-24
4   18/11/2021      Solar  Application submitted 2023-11-18
5   25/06/2020      Solar   Application approved 2021-03-25
6   27/02/2020       Wind  Application submitted 2025-02-25
7   10/03/2022    Battery  Application submitted 2024-03-09
```

Comment: I dont want to merge on the values in DF2 rather my new date should be current date plus the values in DF2 which are number of days as I should have specified. So as in example row 1, 18/03/2022 plus 1095 days is 16/12/2022

Comment: @ChetanPatel - not understand, `18/03/2022 + 1095` days is `2025-03-17`. If not possible use `merge`, what is logic here?

Comment: Sorry! I did the formulas wrong in my example....it should be +273.75 not +1095 you are right